# USB 3.0 to HDMI Converter screen resolution issue

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I recently bought a “USB 3.0 to HDMI Converter Adapter.” I have problem to use it properly. The product is based on [this driver](http://www.frescologic.com/support.php) and am using the latest version (v1.1.315.0).

I have two external displays that have max 1680x1050 resolution. I can’t use the converter higher than 1280x1024 resolution when it is connected to USB 3.0 port of my laptop. I tried it with two different display but doesn’t work properly.

[image]

[image]

The layouts are also wierd that doesn’t fit to the screen. I did “fit to screen” on monitors’ setting menu, factory reset etc but nothing helps.

I am using the latest drivers for my display adapters:

- Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 v10.18.14.4264
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M v10.18.13.5582

Does anyone had the same problem or have any suggestion how I can fix it?

**EDIT:**

I am using Windows 8.1, the driver is only Windows compatible that Linux doesn't recognize it (could get more info). Here is the screen resolution settings.

[image]

The left-most monitor is the USB attached monitor. I can't go higher than than 1280x1024. 1280x800 fills the screen better. I would still be fine if the screen resolution is low but could use it full-screen on the monitor. 
I tried the "converter" on a different laptop (windows 8.1) at USB 3.0 port, result was the same. I tried the product with a square 21" screen and it didn't show any video output at all at any resolution.

I wonder if the "converter" has a defined resolution and if the screen doesn't support, then it doesn't fit to the screen?

Comment: Minor nitpick: It looks as if your 'USB 3.0 to HDMI Converter ' does not convert USb to HDMI, it is a USB attached external graphics cards on a PCE-e 2.0 x1 port.  (source: http://www.frescologic.com/fckimages/1406023488849138436.jpg).

Comment: What OS? What's the display settings? I don't think your installed display cards would matter here

Comment: @journeyman-geek, thank you for the feedback, I updated my question. I was reading discussions on another forum for a similar product, some people claimed that updating their video card drivers solved their issue. As you point, the display cards don't have any effect. I contacted to the driver's developer company some days ago, but don't have hope to get a reply.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/961397/dell-monitor-s2240l-hdmi-full-screen-issue